# Oscommerce 2.3 import to Magento 1.7 using Magmi How do I do it?

Tags: magento, import, export, oscommerce, magmi

I have magmi installed on my domain, magento in one folder fresh install. Oscommerce is in the root. I dont even have the slightest clue as to where to start with magmi! Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

See if this MAGMI WIKI helps you...
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page